# How do I move registration to another event

Tags: civievent, registration, online-registration

I have a member signed up to the wrong event. I can't find a way to switch to the right event through the back end. I see Transfer - but it transfers to another person; not another event. Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not possible via the UI.

There is a table civicrm_participant_payment which links the Participant and the Contribution records.

If you have access to that, and know the contribution_id then you should be able to edit participant_id

Comment: Yes, I do; and yes I do. I didn't want to tinker with the database if there is a way to do it through front end and I missed it! Thank you for confirming :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to the good suggestion by @petednz - fuzion would be to use the API explorer (see https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/)

Comment: Can you share exact steps. I had a quick look at it and didn't see the options to select to get this outcome

Comment: I have not tried @petednz-fuzion but I would assume that i you have the correct record so you can update it in the database I would assume you can also update it with the API ParticipantPayment create? First retrieve the id of the record in question using ParticipantPayment Get and then use the found ID in the ParticipantPayment create.